# Pickling image data and their labels

Tags: python, pickle

I'm new to `pickling` in Python. I have images along with their labels. How can I pickle those?

Comment: If the images are from disk files, it might be better to just store their file paths in the pickle file instead of the image data itself. Images are often quite large, and image-file formats used to store them often employ extremely efficient compression schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure this really qualifies as a valid SO question, my best advice would be to create a class to contain the image data and labels, then implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, as per the descriptions of each at [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). In addition, assuming you are using a library for storing and manipulating the images, look into whether or not it supports pickling, because piggybacking on its implementation could save you a lot of hassle. Hope this helps!